# Have removed summarisation but still adding count when brought into graph - Power BI

Tags: charts, powerbi, visualization, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to just show a flat line of 20 across a graph. I've added a column in my Shift Activity table that's just 20 for every value.

[image]

I've set it to a whole number data type and I've selected "Don't Summarize"

[image]

However when I bring this field into the yaxis of my graph I it consistently summarises it as  "Count of Target"

[image]

And the graph shows the count, not a horizontal line of the value.

[image]

Thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a constant line, don't add any data but add a reference line instead.

[image]